# Mock OutputStream#flush method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, java-io

**I've got:** I have method `void` method of service class. This method takes some data from remote and than flush them with `OutputStream`.

```
public void pullAndFlushData(URI uri, Params params) {
  InputStream input = doHttpRequest(uri, params);
  OutputStream output = new OutputStream("somepath");
  IOUtils.copyLarge(input, output);
  output.flush();
  output.close();
}
```

**I want:** To test the results of this method. So I want to mock `output.flush()` and check whether it contains correct data.

**Question:** How to mock `OutputStream#flush method`?

Comment: If you accept an `OutputStream` as an argument to your method, you could test the method by passing a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and testing the contents. I see no opportunity for mocking with your current code.

Comment: Note: your method doesn't do anything useful. I guess this is because you've simplified it for this question. I think you've over-simplified it, which will make it harder for us to advise how to test it.

Comment: @Duncan I don't accept `OutputSteam` as argument to my method. `IOUtils` is a 3rd party Google class

Comment: @Duncan It takes data from some service, and save them to files. Yes it can modify the data btw that two actions. But that really doesn't matter in this case

Comment: I was suggesting that you should *add* an argument. Sometimes your code needs to change to make it test-able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code won't work:

```
 OutputStream output = new OutputStream("SomePath");
```

... won't compile because OutputStream is abstract.

So somewhere you're going to need to tell the method what OutputStream to use. To make it more testable, make the stream a parameter.

```
 public void pullAndFlushData(OutputStream output, URI uri, Params params) {
    InputStream input = doHttpRequest(uri, params);
    IOUtils.copyLarge(input, output);
    output.flush();
    output.close();
 }
```

Alternatively, `output` could be a field in the object, populated by the constructor or a setter. Or you could pass the object a factory. Whichever of these you choose, it means that the caller can take control of what kind of OutputStream is used -- for the production code, a `FileOutputStream`; for tests, a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

You may wish to review the decision to `close()` the OutputStream here - and instead do it in the same block as the OutputStream is opened.

Now you can test it by having your unit test supply an OutputStream.

```
@Test
public void testPullAndFlushData() {
     URI uri = ...;
     Params params = ...;
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     someObject.pullAndFlushData(baos, uri, params);
     assertSomething(..., baos.toByteArray());
}
```

This doesn't use Mockito, but it's a good pattern for testing methods that use OutputStream.

You could let Mockito mock an OutputStream and use it in the same way - setting expectations for the `write()` calls upon it. But that would become quite brittle about the way `copyLarge()` chunks the data.

You could also use Mockito's `spy()` to check that calls were made to your real ByteArrayOutputStream.

```
@Test
public void testPullAndFlushData() {
     URI uri = ...;
     Params params = ...;
     ByteArrayOutputStream spybaos = spy(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
     someObject.pullAndFlushData(spybaos, uri, params);
     assertSomething(..., spybaos.toByteArray());
     verify(spybaos).flush(); // asserts that flush() has been called.
}
```

However, note that the Mockito team was quite reluctant to provide `spy()`, and in most cases doesn't believe it's a good way to test. Read the [Mockito docs](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) for reasons.

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was thinking. (Although I was lazy and wrote a comment not a nice answer). I would almost consider deleting  your last few paragraphs - we don't want new users thinking this is a good way to test.

Comment: @Duncan he did specifically want to check flush() though. I'm going to mention that the Mockito team don't approve.